# include a variable into a template in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angularJs. I would like to include a variable into a popover template.

```js
angular.forEach($scope.myList, function (obj) {    
      obj.details = '<div uib-popover-html="' + template/template.html + '" type="button"' +
                'popover-placement="bottom" name="' + obj.id+'" id="' + obj.id+'" ' +
                'popover-trigger="\'click\'"> ' +
                '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eur"></i></div>';
```

The template is quite simple:

```html
<div>
  <button ng-click="onClick(object.id)"></button>
</div>
```

What is my problem is I don't know how to link this object.id with the forEach. So, for me it is just a template with a param.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: You should do it with ngRepeat: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: I cant use a ng-repeat as this content will be included in a table, I need the data in the js